# Verify all columns can convert from varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried a bunch of different ways like using cursors and dynamic SQL, but is there a fast way to verify that all columns in a given table can convert from varchar to float (without altering the table)?

I want to get a print out of which columns fail and which columns pass.

I am trying this method now but it is slow and cannot get the list of columns that pass or error out.

```
drop table users;

select *
into users_1
from users

declare @cols table (i int identity, colname varchar(100))
insert into @cols
select column_name
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'users'
and COLUMN_NAME not in ('ID')

declare @i int, @maxi int
select @i = 1, @maxi = MAX(i) from @cols

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

while(@i <= @maxi)
begin
    select @sql = 'alter table users_1 alter column ' + colname + ' float NULL'
    from @cols
    where i = @i

    exec sp_executesql @sql

    select @i = @i + 1
end
```

I found this code on one of the SQL tutorials sites.

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917414/checking-an-entire-table-by-column-to-find-if-all-columns-can-be-converted-to-fl)?

Comment: You want a fast way to read and validate every value in the table? Maybe you should use the right data type in the first place (and that’s probably not float, either).

Comment: The reason I say the script is nonsense, by the way, is that it can't possibly be what you're using now. At the very least, the first line cannot be `drop table users;`, it must be something like `drop table if exists dbo.users_1;`. But also the tutorials site should be named and shamed because it's awful advice (and probably a source of most or all of your performance problem) to suggest you make an entire copy of the table.

Comment: Do you want to convert all columns to `varchar` (Default length 1 or 30.) and then test if they can be converted to `float`, or only test the columns that are `varchar`? Not `nvarchar`? Is conversion with underflow successful?

Comment: Using a correct datatype in the first place would have been great but business, tech debt, and humans cannot always rewirte 25 years of history in a single project. Imagine rewriting an entire financial system for wells fargo in less than a year? Sometimes you are just constrained to what is in front of you and try to make it better.

Answer (score 3):

Why all the drop/create/alter nonsense? If you just want to *know* if a column *could* be altered, why leave your table in a wacky state, where the columns that can be altered are altered, and the ones that can't just raise errors?

Here's one way to accomplish this with dynamic SQL (and with [some protections](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql)):

```
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(513) = N'dbo.YourTableName';

IF OBJECT_ID(@tablename) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ',
            @tmpl nvarchar(max) = N'[Can $colP$ be converted?] 
      = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT 1 FROM ' + @tablename + N'
        WHERE TRY_CONVERT(float, COALESCE($colQ$,N''0'')) IS NULL
      )
      THEN ''No, $colP$ cannot be coverted'' 
      ELSE ''Yes, $colP$ CAN be converted'' END';
    
    SELECT @sql += STRING_AGG(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(@tmpl, N'$colQ$', 
        QUOTENAME(name)), N'$colP$', name), N',')
      FROM sys.columns
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
      AND name <> N'ID';
      
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

- Working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12ff86156a9b63e32b133e6cc2f01d92)

This is never going to be "fast" - there is no great shortcut to having to read and validate every value in the table.

Comment: I'd honestly question if `float` is even the correct data type; it's often misused. I'm not sure what information for a user is best stored as a base 2 numerical value (hopefully it's not something like their account balance...).

Comment: You are correct, the code is psuedo for masking reasons and is used to get an idea on what's wrong as i am not a mvp db sql server guy either. float is correct value for what the business process is, and varchar deals with humans and tech debt. thx for finally giving me an answer and guidance.

Comment: @cdub “finally”?